# What Is The Cause Of This Small Red Icon Appearing Top Left On My Screen Randomly During Gaming?

Tags: icons

(I hope this is the right community to ask this question)

I have an Asus ROG PG279Q monitor connected to an nVidia 1080 Ti card from EVGA, Windows 10 Pro, and an Asus motherboard.

Randomly, say once a month, I will see the icon below appear overlaid on my monitor (top left), about three times the height of the icon below the top of the monitor, then it will glide upwards and out of the top of the monitor, taking about 4 seconds all in all, when I play Starcraft II. It clearly is not generated by my monitor as I pressed PrintScrn to capture this image, meaning it was in video RAM.

What is causing this icon and what is the meaning? I cannot see that the hardware is overheating as I have a mighty liquid cooling solution.

[image]

Comment: Just as an FYI, but this might be a better fit for the [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (Gaming) Stack Exchange if you want to post something like this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/46suif/anyone_else_experience_this_red_memory_icon_in/) links to this [Blizzard post](https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/heroes-of-the-storm/19085485/performance-notification-updates) on a Heros of the Storm update which identifies that icon as a "performance notification icon". Apparently, the game may be attempting to let you know there is a "resource cache" issue.

Assuming these icons are standard across the Blizzard launcher games, the suggested "fix" in that article is to try lowering your in-game texture quality.

Comment: Yeah that looks like it.  Just strange - I am on ultra settings in SC II but have 11GB of VRAM on my 1080 Ti so it is hard to believe this is an accurate error - the stats show SC II uses no more than 3-4GB of my VRAM when playing... Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Just speculation, but maybe there is some quirk in the notification programming, where not all of the VRAM is recognized. I am guessing most video cards don't have that much ;)